# How to construct NEO4j db from 60GB file?

Tags: java, database, neo4j, dbpedia, large-scale

I'm constructing graph database of [`dbpedia - 2014`](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2014/en/) it consists of about **60GB** triple text files. What would be time and memory effective solution for this?
My machine has:

1. RAM - 8gb
2. CPU - 2.20 ghz
3. HD - 500 GB (HDD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this project: https://github.com/mirkonasato/graphipedia

Then your computer is enough, just make sure to use a SSD.

Comment: This question comes up often enough I wonder if eventually someone will do the load on a regular basis and then torrent the resulting database.